# Looping throught SQL output in Javascript block

Tags: sqlx, dataform

Is this possible to execute `.map` function to SQL query ouptput? Like this for example:

```
js {
const tables = `(SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(col1) AS my_array
  FROM
  ${ref("some_ref")})`

const selectAllFromTables = tables.map(t => {
    return `select * from \`${t}\``;
}).join(`
union all
`);
}

${selectAllFromTables}
```

It returns me the following error `assets.map is not a function`